# Grails Default Sorting an Association(bidirectional one-to-many)

Tags: sorting, grails, associations, default

I am trying to default sort an association, my domain classes  are as follows

```
Class Section{
    Integer displayOrder
    static hasMany=[questionCategories:QuestionCategory]

    static mapping={
        questionCategories sort:'displayOrder'
    }
}

Class QuestionCategory{
    Integer displayOrder
    static hasMany=[questions:Question]

    static mapping={
        questions sort:'displayOrder'
    }
}

Class Question{
    Integer displayOrder
}
```

basically i want to get a list of section objects which is sorted by section class's displayOrder, the inner questionCategories sorted by questionCatgory Class's displayOrder and similarly questions sorted by Question class's displayOrder

I have tried SortedSet approach and that works fine, but unfortunately we cannot use it

with this configuration i am getting this error

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "QUESTIONCA3_"."DISPLAY_ORDER": invalid identifier
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like your database is not setup correctly.  One of your underlying tables doesn't have a "DISPLAY_ORDER" column.  Judging by the "QUESTIONCA3_" I'd guess it's the table related to QuestionCategory.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply, i have checked properly, all the tables have DISPLAY_ORDER column